# What is best way to execute multiple HTTP request when App initialize

Tags: angular

In my Angular app. I need to execute multiple(6) HTTP requests(different sources) when the app is initializing.im currently use the `app_initializer` and `promise.all()` for archive this but the problem is my app is blocked until all the HTTP calls are executed. what kind of solution I can use for this

in my metaService.ts I have a method `requestDataFromMultipleSources()`

```
  public requestDataFromMultipleSources() {
    return Promise.all([
    this.loadEduTypes(),
    this.loadCatTypes(),
    this.loadTransportationTypes(),
    this.loadCertificate(),
    this.loadVehical(),
    this.loadLicense(),
    this.loadCountries(),
    this.loadDataTypes(),
    this.loadProfession()
    ])
  }
```

in my app module.ts

```
providers: [
    MetaServices,
    {
      // Provider for APP_INITIALIZER
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: metaServiceFactory,
      deps: [MetaDataServices],
      multi: true
    },

  ],
//this function is used to excute my metaService method
  export function metaDataFactory(metaDataService: MetaDataServices) {
    return () => metaDataService.requestDataFromMultipleSources();
  }
```

Comment: Do not preload them. Load them when you need them. And use shareReplay() to cache the result if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

The `APP_INTIALIZER` **must** resolve before the application loads. So it's working as intended.

If you just need to make the calls **when** the app is initializing (instead of **before** the app initializes) then run the `promise.all` in the `app.component` file instead (which is the first component *by default* to be bootstrapped).

> The APP_INITIALIZER token is used when you want to get the application's configuration details from an API and keep it ready before the application renders the page.
>
> It's similar to how the resolve attribute in the router's configuration is used to get data from the remote API and feed it into the route's data source. In this case, the remote API is resolved first and then the application continues with the bootstrap process.

Further reading: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-the-app-initializer-token-to-hook-into